# How should i ask my boss about remote work that he promised?

Tags: communication, benefits, remote-work

A few months ago I received a raise that came with the possibility of one day of remote work per week. The raise was reflected on my salary on the next pay but the remote work wasn't. How should I approach my employer in a professional manner to ask him about it?

If it means something I'm a junior with just one year of experience, that's why I'm a little insecure about how to handle this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *The raise was reflected on my salary on the next pay **but the remote work wasn't.***

How do you know it has not been *reflected*?

The perk *entitles* you to have the facility, but does not impose that on you. In other words, no one is going to come to you and ask which day you want to avail WFH facility. Just like no one asks you to use the coffee machine next to water cooler - it's there, feel free to use it when you like / need.

Drop a mail to your manager expressing the willingness to avail the facility and discuss the day(s) that would work for you and your team / boss.

Answer (score 3):

> How should i approach my employer in a professional manner to ask about it?

Approach your boss with something similar to:

> Hey boss, thanks for the raise! I notice that it comes with the offer of working one day a week remotely; that's something I'd be interested in exploring. How would you suggest moving forward?

Answer (score 1):

Ask for it over an email. Just keep it simple.

*Hello **XYZ**,*

*I would like to work from home on [so and so date] as agreed a month ago. Let me know if my presence in office is needed on the day
and I will work it out accordingly.*

*Regards*

It's a privilege granted to you, but no one's gonna come and tell you to exercise. You'll have to ask for it.

Based on nature of your job, this could be either a WFH on a fixed day of week of any one day during the week. Just discuss it with your Boss/HR.

You may be unsure the first time if you have never worked from home. Once it works out well a few times, you won't be dwelling this much about it.

Comment: I'd add "as agreed" to the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, like "I'd like to work from home, as agreed, on ..."